# i want to transfer amount from ride booking to ride owner so getting error

Tags: solidity, contract-development, blockchain, tokens

```
// RideSharingContract.sol
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract RideSharingContract {
    address public owner;

    event RideCreated(address indexed creator, uint256 indexed rideId, string source, string destination, uint256 fare, uint256 seatsAvailable, uint256 date, uint256 time);
    event RideBooked(address indexed rider, address indexed rideOwner, uint256 indexed rideId, string source, string destination, uint256 bookedSeats, uint256 fare);
    event BalanceUpdated(uint256 newBalance);
    event OwnerBalanceUpdated(address indexed owner, uint256 newOwnerBalance);

    struct Ride {
        address payable creator;
        string source;
        string destination;
        uint256 fare;
        uint256 seatsAvailable;
        uint256 date;
        uint256 time;
        mapping(address => uint256) bookedSeats;
    }

    Ride[] public rides;

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Not the contract owner");
        _;
    }

    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function createRide(string memory _source, string memory _destination, uint256 _fare, uint256 _seatsAvailable, uint256 _date, uint256 _time) public {
        uint256 rideId = rides.length;
        rides.push();
        Ride storage newRide = rides[rideId];
        
        newRide.creator = payable(msg.sender);
        newRide.source = _source;
        newRide.destination = _destination;
        newRide.fare = _fare;
        newRide.seatsAvailable = _seatsAvailable;
        newRide.date = _date;
        newRide.time = _time;

        emit RideCreated(msg.sender, rideId, _source, _destination, _fare, _seatsAvailable, _date, _time);
    }

    function bookRide(uint256 _rideId, uint256 _seatsToBook) public payable {
        require(_rideId < rides.length, "Invalid ride ID");
        Ride storage ride = rides[_rideId];
        require(ride.seatsAvailable >= _seatsToBook, "Not enough seats available");
        require(ride.bookedSeats[msg.sender] == 0, "You have already booked a seat");

        uint256 totalFare = _seatsToBook * ride.fare;
        require(msg.value >= totalFare, "Insufficient ether sent for the fare");

        // Check if the user has enough balance to perform the transaction
        require(address(this).balance >= totalFare, "Contract does not have enough funds");

        // Use transfer for the Ether transfer to the ride creator
        ride.creator.transfer(totalFare);

        ride.seatsAvailable -= _seatsToBook;
        ride.bookedSeats[msg.sender] = _seatsToBook;

        emit RideBooked(msg.sender, ride.creator, _rideId, ride.source, ride.destination, _seatsToBook, totalFare);
        emit BalanceUpdated(address(this).balance);
        emit OwnerBalanceUpdated(ride.creator, ride.creator.balance);
    }

    function getRideDetails(uint256 _rideId) public view returns (
        address creator,
        string memory source,
        string memory destination,
        uint256 fare,
        uint256 seatsAvailable,
        uint256 date,
        uint256 time
    ) {
        require(_rideId < rides.length, "Invalid ride ID");

        Ride storage ride = rides[_rideId];

        creator = ride.creator;
        source = ride.source;
        destination = ride.destination;
        fare = ride.fare;
        seatsAvailable = ride.seatsAvailable;
        date = ride.date;
        time = ride.time;
    }
    
    function getUserBalance() public view returns (uint256) {
        return msg.sender.balance;
    }
}
```

this is the code while on ride booking the fare amount is not deposited on the ride owner instead of remix contract balance is increases

[image: balance eth deposited instead of ride owner address]